# Calendar with no milliseconds vs Calendar with milliseconds that are 0

Tags: java, calendar, timestamp, milliseconds, java.util.calendar

I cannot figure out how to tell if a `Calendar` object was created with no milliseconds *versus* a Calendar object that was created with milliseconds that happens to have a value 0.

I need to distinguish between the time stamps

```
2018 04 30 13:44:55 -0500
and
2018 04 30 13:44:55.000 -0500
```

The latter shows that the time clock is reporting time with a resolution to milliseconds while the former is only reporting time with a resolution to seconds. So in the latter case I want to display the '000' but in the former I do not.

`Calendar.get(Calendar.MILLISECONDS) = 0` clearly does not solve this problem. Any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: What is the context?  Can `Calendar` be avoided, and use a `LocalDateTime`?

Comment: For new time classes: `LocalDateTime.isSupported(ChronoField.MILLI_OF_SECOND)`

Comment: @JoopEggen That will always return true. `LocalDateTime` has precision of nanoseoncds. Always.

Comment: Brian, what is the scenario in which you need this? I was thinking, if you are parsing a date-time string that either has milliseconds in it or not, and you need to give the same string back, you might just keep the string around in addition to your (as I recommend) `OffsetDateTime` object. It’s redundant, but might solve your problem? (The `Calendar` class is long outmoded and poorly designed, so I would avoid that.)

Comment: At the moment I am kind of stuck with Calendar since libraries I need use it.

Comment: @AndrewS `LocalDateTime` is the wrong class to use, as it does *not* represent a moment.  `ZonedDateTime` is the replacement for `Calendar`. And `Instant` replaces `java.util.Date` for a moment in UTC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Calendar::isSet(int)` method will test if a specific field has been set.

Comment: Indeed, `new GregorianCalendar(2018, Calendar.JANUARY, 22, 23, 59, 48).isSet(Calendar.MILLISECOND)` yields `false`.

Comment: Yes, I discovered that and gave it a try and it did indeed solve my problem. I must also being doing something wrong on stack overflow; I never get notifications in my email of any responses to my questions or comments ... though I believe I have correctly signed up for them ...